# Saving previous date and adding new date in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have been working on an application where user adds his tasks which he is supposed to perform, once the task is added he can update the progress.

In my model I have a date field, where user is supposed to enter the estimated completion date.

My task model

```
"""Creating KRA Based on Institutional Objectives"""
class KraBasedOnIo(models.Model):
    io = models.ForeignKey(InstitutionalObjectives, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='kra_io')
    kra_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    kra_description = models.TextField()
    kra_target = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    kra_added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    estimated_date = models.????
```

While updating the progress, if the user wants to extend his timeline, I am looking for an option where I can save his current estimated completion date and add the new date also.

And when I am displaying his progress I want to show his **defined completion date** and also the **extended completion date** in the template.

I have tried a work around with model.JSONField() but couldn't reach there.

There is no ListField or DictionaryField so what could be a better solution for this?

Comment: Why not adding another field `updated_estimated_field` ?

Comment: But user can extend the date n number of times, that's why I want to store it as a list or dict or date.

Comment: As per the requirements it can be extended once, twice or even thrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would use the library [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to keep track of the different updates of this field.

```
"""Creating KRA Based on Institutional Objectives"""
class KraBasedOnIo(models.Model):
    io = models.ForeignKey(InstitutionalObjectives, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='kra_io')
    kra_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    kra_description = models.TextField()
    kra_target = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    kra_added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    estimated_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Then in you view, you can see the different version by doing :

```
for record in kra_based_on_info.history.all():
    print(record)
```

Comment: It's working as expected, thank you for the quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and create two separated fields:

```
class KraBasedOnIo(models.Model):
    # ...
    estimated_completion_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    extended_completion_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

If you need to keep track of all the completion date changes, I suggest you to create a new model

```
class CompletionDate(models.Model):
    # ...
    kra = models.ForeignKey(KraBasedOnIo, related_name='completion_dates', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estimated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And then get the last completion date for a KraBasedOnIo instance like this:

```
my_last_completion_date = KraBasedOnIo.completion_dates.last()
```